# AngularJS - When to service what

Tags: angularjs

So, over the last month I've been diving pretty hard into AngularJS and my controllers got extremely big. I decided to learn about factories and services so I could separate some of my logic...which leads me to my question.

I see a lot of examples online where people are using ajax calls to the server from their controllers. Is this a good practice? The more I study AngularJS and compare it to what I already know about software design, I see the controller's job pass data into the view. Much like a controller in MVC, where business logic shouldn't exist. Is that a safe assumption?

Also -- If I were to move my ajax calls over to a factory or service, would the functionality be the same? Something like below?

**Service**

```
app.service('orderService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var orderdata = {};
    // Gets orders from WebAPI
    this.getRecentOrders = function () {
        $http.get('/api/orders').success(function (data) {
            this.orderdata = data;
        });
        return this.orderdata;

    };
}]);
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.recentOrders = orderService.getRecentOrders();
```

**edit**
I had to modify the code in the controller slightly from the answer to get it to work correctly:

```
orderService.getRecentOrders().then(function(result) {
    $scope.recentOrders = result.data;
});
```

Comment: I'm hesitant to describe this as an "answer" because it is mostly a matter of opinion. We have build a bunch of Angular applications, and teach Angular classes, and our advice in class is approximately as you described - controllers are for the UI, move logic around talking to a server in to service/factory. Prefer .service because it is more similar to how Angular 2 works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services should return an object with methods. Also, the method you invoke should return the promise as it's an async call, so the `return this.orderdata` will always be `undefined` (or at least the first time):

```
app.service('orderService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        getRecentOrders: function () {
            return $http.get('/api/orders');
        }
    };
}]);
```

No with this, you can chain to that promise in order to get the data in your controller:

```
orderService.getRecentOrders().then(function(data) {
    $scope.recentOrders = data;
});
```

Now as per the question itself, basically, controllers should be "dumb", what does this mean? it should not have any heavy logic within. It should only be the layer that gets data from the services, and use them to show them in the `$scope`. Everything related to heavy logic (data processing and such) should be apart from the controller. That's why angular provides you with Filters, Services and Directives.

Comment: Thank you for you help and insight.